# How to Remove the Data in a Specific Column for the Duplicate IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have this simple dataframe:

```
ID  Name    State
1   John    DC
1   John    VA
2   Smith   NE
3   Janet   CA
3   Janet   NC
3   Janet   MD
```

I want to delete the `State` value for the duplicate `IDs` like so:

```
ID  Name    State
1   John    nan
1   John    nan
2   Smith   NE
3   Janet   nan
3   Janet   nan
3   Janet   nan
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated` returns a boolean mask where rows are duplicated over the columns defined in `subset`.  `keep=False` indicates that we shouldn't consider the first or last of the duplicates as non-duplicate.  Using `loc` then allows us to assign to the rows where duplicates happen.

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['ID'], keep=False), 'State'] = None

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In[25]:df['State']=np.where(df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False),np.nan,df['State'])

In[26]:df
Out[26]: 
   ID   Name State
0   1   John   NaN
1   1   John   NaN
2   2  Smith    NE
3   3  Janet   NaN
4   3  Janet   NaN
5   3  Janet   NaN
```

*Timings:*

```
%timeit df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['ID'], keep=False), 'State'] = None
100 loops, best of 3: 2.32 ms per loop

%timeit df['State']=np.where(df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False),np.nan,df['State'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 657 µs per loop
```

Comment: You beat me to it, But df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False)==True, >>> df['Name'].duplicated(keep=False),  .... dont need '==True'